# How can i stop for loop iteartion in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to stop for loop after few rows are executed in my code

```
cursor.execute("select score*100 from daily_stats1 where  user_id=102")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
# Convert query to objects of key-value pairs
lastweek1 = list()
i = 0
for row in rows:
    lastweek1.append(row[i])
    if i == 4:
        break
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: your not incrementing `i` in your code

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense to me - you want to break when `i == 4`. But you have fixed `i = 0` and never increment it. What are you trying to break out of? Maybe you want to say -
    if rows.index(row) == 4:
        break
??

Comment: I want to print only 4 rows

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mortz

Comment: Posted the comment as an answer - Select a right answer so that this question is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for row in rows[:4]:
    lastweek1.append(row)
```

or you can do it with list compression like this:

```
lastweek1 = [row for row in rows[:4]]
```

Comment: your welcome, if you find my answer helpfull please check the gray button beside.

Answer (score 2):

You never incremented your `i`. Either do that, or leave it to `enumerate`. Also, with your clarification that you want to print only 4 rows, you'd better do the check at the top of the loop, as you'll otherwise be printing 5:

```
lastweek1 = list()
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    if i == 4:
        break
    lastweek1.append(row)
```

Or you could not complicate it :). The first four whole rows is as simple as

```
lastweek1 = rows[:4]
```

or if it's a generator (which is likely) and you need to reify it,

```
lastweek1 = list(rows[:4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense to me - you want to break when `i == 4`. But you have fixed `i = 0` and never increment it. What are you trying to break out of? Maybe you want to say -

```
if rows.index(row) == 4:
    break
```

??